Oracle Linux does not detect Hyper-V network interface
I'm facing an issue after migrating an Oracle Linux VM from ESXi to Hyper-V running on Windows Server 2019. When I start the VM and run the command:
ip a

I only see the loopback interface, with no other network interfaces listed.
I've already tried installing:
yum install dhclient dhcp-common dracut-network

and then running:
dracut -f

However, after rebooting the VM, the problem persists. Do you have any suggestions or ideas on how to fix this?

Are you using synthetic or legacy nic?

Hi, in my Hyper-V i dont have any option to use the legacy nic, and my VM is in Hyper-V generation 1
